# Fatal error: Call to a member function IPP() on a non-object in QuickBooks/IPP/Service.php on line 417

Tags: quickbooks

I downloaded https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php to a php server.  Then I filled out `docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/config.php` with the developer keys and put in a mysql database credential.  As soon as I ran the `docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php` script in my browser, I get the error

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: Context in /var/www/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php on line 54



Notice:  Undefined variable: realm in /var/www/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php on line 54



Fatal error:  Call to a member function IPP() on a non-object in /var/www/QuickBooks/IPP/Service.php on line 417
```

What did I do wrong?  How do I correct this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way this can happen is if you didn't actually connect to QuickBooks yet.

Did you visit the `index.php` script to actually connect to QuickBooks prior to visiting `example_customer_add.php`?

Does `index.php` say that you've successfully connnected to QuickBooks?

Comment: Oh right, should have read the installation instructions more carefully

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I had a similar problem. The error occurred when I did an action with the API, from inside of a function. I.e.:

```
function foo () {
   $CustomerService->query($Context, $realm, ...
   ...
```

The problem was the global variables $Context and $realm were not accessible from inside the function, you need to use **global** to import before using them.

```
global $Context, $realm;
```